# Centering Figures with Captions

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I'm sorry if  this is a repost, but this is something I've been researching on here for awhile now and I can't seem to come up with the right answer. I'm trying to get these images to appear in the exact center of the page with the captions underneath, but they keep going on the left side of the page.

Here's my html

```
<figure>
    <img src="apple.jpg" alt='apple/>
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>           
</figure>       
<figure>
    <img src="apple.jpg" alt='apple'/>
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>           
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="apple.jpg" alt='apple'/>
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>           
</figure>
```

And the css

```
figure{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
figure img{
   vertical-align: top;                 
}
figure figcaption{
   text-align: center;
}
```

Here's what I see:

[image]

Thanks in advance. I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: in figure img, try adding display: block; and setting left and right margins to auto. https://jsfiddle.net/bvabamyy/

Comment: I tried that and nothing changes

Comment: Do you want the 3 imgs side-by-side at the center or on 3 rows? Only horizontal center or vertical center aswell?

Comment: I misunderstood your question at first.

Comment: Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/bvabamyy/2/

Comment: I'd like them side by side in the exact center of the page, with captions underneath in the exact center of the images.

Comment: Adding to Dan's answer: https://jsfiddle.net/bvabamyy/2/

Comment: Is the myclass container containing the whole figure portion in the html code?

Comment: @JordanGates take a look at my updated version in full page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want them horizontally or vertically aligned?

vertically:

```
figure {
  display: block;
  text-align: center
}
```

horizontally:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center
}
```

Comment: The "horizontally" option aligns them vertically.

Answer (score 0):

## **Update**

OP has clarified that the images are to be side-by-side and centered vertically as well.

- Place everything in a div or section (any block element will do)
- I used a `section` with the following styles:

  - `display: table;` will make it act like a table
  - `height: 100vh;`  will make it as tall as the viewport (your screen)
  - `margin: 0 auto;` auto will adjust left and right until both are equal
- Added the following to the figures:

  - `display: table-cell;` will make it act like a table cells
  - `vertical-align : middle;` will actually work on table cells

**Updated Snippet**

```css
section {
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
figure {
  vertical-align : middle;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
figure img {
  width: 20em;
}
figure figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/r3m3gMJ.jpg" alt='apple' />
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/r3m3gMJ.jpg" alt='apple' />
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/r3m3gMJ.jpg" alt='apple' />
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

---

---

- There's a "'" (single quote) missing on the first `alt`

- Change figure to `block` or remove it as I did since figure is `display: block` by default.
- Add `text-align: center` to `figure`

Note: the original image was off center (of course), so I edited it to be symmetrical.

See snippet below.

**Snippet**

```css
figure {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
figure img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20em;
}
figure figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/r3m3gMJ.jpg" alt='apple' />
  <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/r3m3gMJ.jpg" alt='apple' />
  <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/r3m3gMJ.jpg" alt='apple' />
  <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your elements with Div container to control the position. 
This is a hacky way of doing it.  But you can adjust the .center class to get it where you want on the page, i.e. adjust the right: and/or left properties.

```
.container {
    position: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
}

figure{
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0 auto;
}
figure img{
                vertical-align: top;                    
}
figure figcaption{
                text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
<figure>
    <img src="apple.jpg" alt='apple/>
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>           
</figure>       
<figure>
    <img src="apple.jpg" alt='apple'/>
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>           
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="apple.jpg" alt='apple'/>
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>           
</figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>           
</figure>       
<figure>
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>           
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>           
</figure>
```

css

```
figure{

                width:30%;
                display:inline-block;
               margin:1%;
               margin-left:1.5%;




}
figure img{
                width:100%;
                 display:block;
                  margin-left:auto;  
                  margin-right:auto;
}
figure figcaption{
                text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljdxnwot/3/

Comment: This worked, but also greatly enlarged the images. Is there any way to adjust that?

Comment: Yes possible , i use in my projects genereally grids for this .